# Flag large number random records in a MySQL database - one time only

Tags: mysql, random

In my database table I've got 5 columns, `id, l_num, s_num, win, claimed`. There are 415,000 records. How would I randomly select 20,000 of those records and update the record with a `1` in the `win` field?

I understand that I could use `SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20000` to select those random records, but I've also read that this type of select would be inefficient for a large number.

I only need to perform this once on the database. Once all the records are flagged, we're simply checking against that flag one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
UPDATE tableName SET win = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20000
```

Comment: Thank you. This will accommodate a change that the client just notified me of very well.

Answer (score 0):

Each record has a probability of 20000/415000 = 0,04819... of being chosen.

So you could select all records where RAND() is less than 0.049. This will select about 20335 records, and from *these* you can run a LIMIT 20000.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE RAND() < (20000/415000)*1.05 LIMIT 20000;
```

Above, I added a 5% margin to be "reasonably" sure of selecting enough records.

Same can be done for an `UPDATE` query, of course, i.e.

```
UPDATE tableName SET ... WHERE RAND() < (20000/415000)*1.05 LIMIT 20000;
```

Experimentally the probability of this method selecting less than 20000 records is 7% using a margin of 1.01, 0.5% with a margin of 1.02, and below 0.05% with a margin of 1.03.

Another drawback of this method is that selection isn't really random, in that the last records have a lower probability of being chosen (since the quota of 20,000 records is extremely likely to be satisfied before the full table has been examined).

To add a "winning code", you can use the same method (albeit even more approximate at this point)

```
... SET win = CASE WHEN RAND() BETWEEN 0 AND .333 THEN 'potting soil' WHEN RAND() BETWEEN .333 AND .666 THEN 'gift certificate' ELSE 'something else' END WHERE RAND() < ...
```

Here you need to carefully adjust the values, since RAND() is calculated once at each invocation. So if you wanted to equally divide between 3 possibilities, this would **not** work:

```
CASE WHEN RAND() BETWEEN 0 AND 0.333   THEN 1
     WHEN RAND() BETWEEN .333 AND .666 THEN 2
     ELSE                                   3
END
```

because the first case would be chosen 33% of the times (which is correct), then the second case would be chosen 33% of the *remaining* times, which is 2/9ths, and the third would cover the rest (4/9ths). To equally divide the range you would need 33%, 50% and 50%:

```
mysql> SELECT r, count(*)/1048576.0 FROM (select case when rand() between 0 and 0.333 then 1 when rand() between 0.333 and 0.666 then 2 else 3 end AS r from numbers) AS a GROUP BY r;
+---+--------------------+
| r | count(*)/1048576.0 |
+---+--------------------+
| 1 |             0.3330 |
| 2 |             0.2218 |
| 3 |             0.4452 |
+---+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT r, count(*)/1048576.0 FROM (select case when rand() between 0 and 0.333 then 1 when rand() between 0 and 0.5 then 2 else 3 end AS r from numbers) AS a GROUP BY r;
+---+--------------------+
| r | count(*)/1048576.0 |
+---+--------------------+
| 1 |             0.3324 |
| 2 |             0.3337 |
| 3 |             0.3339 |
+---+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Note that the division is only probabilistic - you don't actually get *exactly* 1/3, 1/3 and 1/3.

Another possibility would be to assign a random integer to every record, with sufficient graininess (e.g. a random number from 0 to 415,000,000), index on it, and (a) find by bisection a value K so that the number of people with index below K are exactly 20,000, (b) assign prizes based on modulo (i.e., everyone with ndx % 100 between 0 and 33 gets the gift certificate. If you need to frequently run this kind of operations, assigning a "destiny" number to each participant might be worthwhile.

If the number of extractions compared to the total is large (as it is in this case), definitely go with Salman's more precise solution.

Comment: That is an incredibly robust answer! I chose @salman-a based on some information that just came in from the client. They want to add a code to the win field now, not just a `1`.

Comment: ...add a code? I'm afraid I don't understand. As for robustness, I'm afraid Salman's better; I do avoid the search, but there *is* a slight possibility that less than 20,000 records will be selected. (You can make it unlikelier and unlikelier, but *theoretically* it will always be possible).

Comment: You would still want to `order by rand()` after the `limit`.  Otherwise, you may miss rows at the end of the table.

Comment: By code, I mean to say that the client wants to have different 'kinds' of winners, i.e. `a` wins potting soil, `b` wins a gift certificate, etc.